# Problems with DataGridView when add new items

Tags: c#, datagridviewcomboboxcell

When I save a new item on datagridview the statement

```
MessageBox.Show(this.tb_aprovacao_admissaoDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```

shows the value -1. How can I change it to show the real number of ID?

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: -1 means it isn't found, so something wrong with the search itself, can you show some more code, might be because you request something to early or so.

Comment: Are you trying to save an item, then show that item, or are you trying to just save the item/ show the item?

Comment: the datagridveiw show -1 on ID when I am editing a new item. And I need the ID number to include on foreign key of other table.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you want to get the value.. 
Do you want to get the value after you click on the cell, or on the click of a button or?

If you want to do it on the cell click event, you can do it like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value != null)
            {
                 MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
```

To get it with a button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: When I add a new item the first number displayed on ID is -1. And when update the datagridview this item show its ID with real value (Ex. 7). I need this real number of ID for include on foreign key on other table after save this new item.